# Even Simple Next.js API timeout on Vercel

Tags: next.js, serverless, nextjs-api-router

Every API in the NextJS project is giving a 504 bad gateway time out error only in vercel production deployment, everything works fine in local, so I added a hello GET API with the sample code.

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Hello from Next.js!' })
}
```

but this does fail too with 504

> *504: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT Code: FUNCTION_INVOCATION_TIMEOUT*

this is the [link](https://glomium-dashboard.vercel.app/api/hello/).

When I checked the vercel log the API sometimes rarely works for once and then starts to fail with 504 again.

My code is located at src\pages\api in the root

Answer (score -1):

This is because the URL is "wrong". You use https://glomium-dashboard.vercel.app/api/hello/ but this file would be at https://glomium-dashboard.vercel.app/api/hello (without forward slash at the end) and is working nicely.

The URL you are trying to reach (with forward slash at the end) would map to an `index` file under src/pages/api/hello/ or should redirect to URL without slash. I guess you might have a conflicting URL somewhere.

Comment: Both the URLs are the same. if you hit https://glomium-dashboard.vercel.app/api/hello it will redirect to https://glomium-dashboard.vercel.app/api/hello/. your index logic is completely wrong.

Comment: Didn't redirect like that earlier. And, if any redirect happens by default, that should be without slash to with slash so I guess you have the `trailingSlash`set to `true` in nextjs.config.js. And now I don't get timeouts on any of those 2 URLs

Comment: Yeah, i fixed it by changing the server function location. before that when working both works, else both doesnot work. and the thing about redirect, its vercel default, i didn't change a anthing in nextjs.config.js.